# Comparing two NULL-able variables in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have two variables which may be NULL, and I want to check if they are different.

**But**, I want to:

- Treat two NULLs as equal (not as NULL).
- Treat NULL and non-NULL as unequal (not as NULL).

I know I could just write:

```
DECLARE @v1 int = ...;
DECLARE @v2 int = ...;

IF (
    (@v1 IS NULL AND @v2 IS NOT NULL)
    OR (@v1 IS NOT NULL AND @v2 IS NULL)
    OR @v1 <> @v2
)
    PRINT 'Different!';
```

But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You can simplify this condition negating it: `NOT (@v1 IS NULL AND @v2 IS NULL OR @v1 = @v2)

Comment: @MarkShevchenko This thinks NULL and 0 are equal.

Comment: Umm, love this kind of tricky questions!

Comment: Why do you care about "Treat NULL and non-NULL as unequal (not as NULL)."? There's no difference in boolean expressions (and SQL doesn't have bool as a data type). `NULL` is false, as far as filters and conditionals are concerned.

Comment: @Luaan This is part of business logic which checks if certain field changed, and triggers certain logic if it did. In the context of that business logic, going from NULL to NULL counts as "no change" and going from NULL to non-NULL (or back) counts as "change".

Comment: To whom it may concern: Apparently there is a [user voice case](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145-add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distin) for this, but has been ignored by MS for more than a decade and was eventually "unplanned". Bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more option but I'm not sure whether it'll be more elegant.

```
IF NOT(NULLIF(@v1, @v2) IS NULL AND NULLIF(@v2, @v1) IS NULL)
PRINT 'Different!';
```

Comment: Nicest answer so far, in my opinion. Performance is also good (equal to "my" IF). Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear it!! If NULLIF function was smarter a bit(Now: if first value NULL then fuction returns NULL, but I would suggest microsoft's developers retrieve seconds value instead of NULL), then we would have even shorter and more elegant solution;)

Answer (score 5):

Just to show there are many ways to do it.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT @v1 EXCEPT SELECT @v2)
    PRINT 'Different'
```

Comment: Behaves correctly, but is roughly 2x slower than my "plain" IF (probably not a problem in most situations), and is more difficult to read (IMHO), so I won't accept it as an answer just yet. Thanks for the effort, though! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @v1 INT = ...;
DECLARE @v2 INT = ...;

IF ISNULL(@v1, -1) <> ISNULL(@v2, -1)
    PRINT 'Different!'
```

Comment: This thinks NULL and -1 are equal.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - it does, but do you really need to support all values in the `int` range? Usually, you can find some kind of sentinel value that shouldn't exist in your real data and use it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I do, unless/until the database is designed and implemented to protect itself from ever having such a value. This is more trouble than it's worth just for making one IF a little shorter.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic By that logic what you have works.

Comment: @Frisbee Sure and I don't mind it too much as it is. It just looks way uglier than something this simple ought to look, so I was wondering if I missed something obvious...

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - in standard SQL, I believe there is a `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` operation available which does exactly what you want. Unfortunately, most current database systems I'm aware of don't implement this part of the standard.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - See [This connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate) asking for it to be added to SQL Server, but feel free to get depressed when you see when it was raised.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Uglier than it ought to look?  Three lines.  Line them up pretty.

Comment: @Frisbee - if you look at what I've just commented here, you can kind of see their point. If SQL Server supported all of SQL 2002 (not that any database product does), it would just be `@v1 IS DISTINCT FROM @v2`, so it could definitely be cleaner.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So would be cleaner.  What is there works and I have definitely done uglier stuff.

Comment: @Frisbee This point is not in this _one_ IF. The point is in striving to avoid a codebase littered with instances of ugliness, each instance being rather simple on its own, but making the code less readable in aggregate. That being said, there are much uglier things out there, I agree.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Now it is aggregate ugly?  So five joins is pretty?   I base my queries on accuracy and performance not pretty.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I can't help you.  Keep it pretty.

Comment: @Frisbee Sure, I'll keep it pretty _and_ correct _and_ fast, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @v1 INT = NULL
DECLARE @v2 INT = 1

IF CHECKSUM(@v1) != CHECKSUM(@v2)
    PRINT 'Different!'
```

Comment: This thinks NULL and 2147483647 are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the wider scenario in which this code will be used, we often use a null-equivalent value, which is a value which is valid for the datatype, but  outside the program's valid range. For example, if your program is only using positive integers, using a null-equivalent value of -1 would mean that the following is possible:

```
IF ISNULL(@v1, -1) != ISNULL(@v2, -1) -- or COALESCE if you prefer
    PRINT 'Different!';
```

If the full range of integer values are valid entries, then it's not possible to use a null-equivalent value. If that's the case, there is absolutely nothing wrong with your original method.

I would advise anyone against getting too clever with things like this, it will just cause you pain later on. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

one more option is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
IF @v1 != @v2 
    PRINT 'Different!';
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

Comment: Thanks, but `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is deprecated. Quote from MSDN: _"In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."_.

Comment: Yes, but in the version of 2012 and earlier, this method should work fine. Any way, answer has been posted just for info, that this task can be performed using this solution. And also, you haven't specified that you have some restriction in usage of the SQL Server version.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to use deprecated features, even when they are still available. Especially if you plan for your software to have a long lifetime...

Answer (score 0):

For those who waited this long... SQL Server 2022 has finally implemented `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` operator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql